# Bootstrap Mobile Alignment vs Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Basically, I am coding a simple page and on desktop, it all aligns just fine. When switched over to mobile it appears very differently. I will include screenshots to show what I mean. I have tested this on Nexus 5, iPhone 6, iPad Air and two different desktop monitors (21in + 17in).

How would I go about fixing this exactly? I am not very advanced in bootstrap but I couldn't find anything in the documentation about mobile.

Also, the alignment of things and their position changes based on size of monitor. Even if I zoom out it will change the position of things and make it look weird.

I guess what I'm wondering is how to make this page more repsonsive!

[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

Here is the code for the section:

```
    <div class="well" style="height:12%;width:75%;">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            Testing12332<br /><br /><a class="link" href="view.php?id=27"><b>Testingthis</b> - 0 seconds</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <form action="like.php?id=27" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:-8%;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">&#9650</button><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="27">
            </form>
            <div class="well" style="padding:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
                0
            </div>
            <form action="dislike.php?id=27" method="POST">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">&#9660;</button><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="27">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Let me know if more information is needed! I tried to provide as much as possible! Also, yes, I am using Bootswatch (Flatly) if that makes a difference.

Edit: All of the code is here --> http://pastebin.com/AvYEkDNN

Sorry for the format being messed up, a lot of it is output with PHP and messed up the format in each loop.

Comment: please post your complete html AND your CSS, remember that you need some context. Right now, if I copy your code "as is" it's a complete mess

Comment: The CSS being used is the latest Bootstrap. I included that in the post. @Devin

Comment: OK, this is how it looks with what you provided http://www.bootply.com/EQ0dpGwnvn . See why I ask you to add your code?

Comment: Start by changing all of your col-md to col-xs.  I'll start reworking the rest of your code now and be back in a few :)

Comment: Thankyou @JakeTaylor, I will get started on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to your complete HTML. http://pastebin.com/ZCvDzz3b The only other thing you need to do is create an external stylesheet if you don't already have one called style.css and then add this code at the bottom of this sheet.  Make sure your style.css is placed in the same location as your index file.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
        .well {width:75%!important;
                height:22%!important;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sweet! I implemented it and it seems fine on Desktop, only issue is that the width exceeds the panel for some reason. Would I just change width; 95% to a smaller width? AS for mobile, it appears the height is too big and the width exceeds just like in the desktop. Works perfectly, just minor tweaks needed in height and width. :)

Comment: Fixed the width issue by keeping it at 95% and putting !important after it.

Comment: As for the height issue, how do I fix that for mobile only users? :) If I change the height under the @media part in .well it will update for Desktop and Mobile. But width is perfect on both mobile and desktop! :)

Comment: How come when I change the height in the main .well then it will update on my desktop also when I'm on a 21 inch monitor? D: And I noticed that when zooming out it will appear differently and same with zooming in. Here is what happens when zooming in: http://i.gyazo.com/993dfa7912185162ae3fbf98da636923.png

Comment: Thankyou for all the hard work man! Take all the time you need. The thing is though, for me it is appearing like this on my desktop, and appears the same on my phone. The good thing is, now there is no difference between my desktop and phone, but when I zoom in or out on my PC it will mess things up. http://i.gyazo.com/66b53f7a09c22ee8161f9390ac1bece9.png

Comment: Here is a link to the website live. Free hosting, so it is a bit slow. http://vindesigns.cf/index.php

Comment: Try adding this: <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
below your <head> tag

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything really, but I did add it below the <head> tag :)

Comment: Huh?  and you added an external stylesheet? It's impossible for me to tell what's going on because of the fact your site's not loading from the link you sent me.  When I run the code locally it works perfectly for me.  So I'm not even sure where to go until I can pull up your site.

Comment: Not sure why its not loading for you :( But I'll try to improvise. Here is all the code updated. http://pastebin.com/gB9BSH2c I do have it in an external stylesheet. Here is a screenshot of the page currently with that code. And also, I believe when I added the meta part, it fixed the zoom in and out issue. http://i.gyazo.com/5511d7ebff74222ab968e64671cced9f.png

Comment: Under your <div class="well"> take our style="height:25%;width:90%;" and then add .well { height:25%; width:90%;} to the top of your stylesheet.  I just realized your css in your html is overriding your stylesheet because of the order it's in.  Technically...all of your styles should be placed on your external stylesheet.

Comment: Didn't seem to fix it, still looks the same :/ As for Mobile, the mobile looks a lot better. Everything fits better, just the buttons for liking and disliking are pressed right up against the side. I could fix this with a margin-right I believe. Fixed the height, in style.css for some reason it was set to 22% instead of 12%. Only issue now is the part where it shows amount of likes being non-centered even though it is set to be and for mobile being pressed up against the side.

Comment: Try changing this <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> to this <link href="http://vindesigns.cf/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  Haven't given up yet :) There's an http:// before vindesigns but it's showing up as a link instead so don't forget the http://

Comment: Everything is fixed now! Working perfectly! :) Thankyou so much man!

Comment: Thank you Baby Jesus!!!  It was a directory issue.  Please accept my answer as the correct if you haven't already.  Oh...and you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the issue thank you to your comment

First of all, do NOT use inline styling. It usually means problems and quite rarely a solution.

With that in mind, get rid of this:

```
<form action="like.php?id=27" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:-8%;">
```

and replace it by

```
<form action="like.php?id=27" method="POST" class="my-custom-form">
```

this will allow you to re-use that style every time.

Now you can do something like this by simply adding some EXTERNAL CSS:

```
.my-custom-form{margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:-8%;}
/** add some styling for small devices **/
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.my-custom-form{margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:1% /* or whatever, just not a negative value */;}
}
```

and it will fix your issue

**EDIT:**

Besides the above, clean your code like this:

```
<div class="well row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-10">testingthis
        <br />
        <br /><a class="link" href="view.php?id=28"><b>Anonymous</b> - 27 minutes ago</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <form action="like.php?id=28" method="POST" class="my-form">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">&#9650</button>
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="28" />
        </form>
        <div class="number">-1</div>
        <form action="dislike.php?id=28" method="POST">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">&#9660;</button>
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="28" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

and also get rid of your  element. With all these changes (plus any additional visual adjustment you may need), it will work on all sizes

Comment: I understand what you mean, and it does make sense. Also, I have updated with a link to ALL of the code :) I have implemented this in the page, and upon refresh everything appears the exact same for both mobile and desktop.

Comment: Would the CSS for my-form be the same as your original CSS before the edit? @Devin Because if so, it does change things for the Desktop, the things are in different places now and rearranged. For the mobile, it still looks the same. Unless I was mistaken and used the wrong code for my-form.